# File compare tool with combined file view feature

Tags: diff

I'm looking for a file compare tool with a "combined file" view. To me, this makes the best use of screenspace because unchanged lines are only shown once and also I don't have to move my eyes much to move from "before" to "after". The screenshot below shows what I mean - the blue and red text show the differences, the black text on white background is the unchanged portion of the file.

I checked Beyond Compare and WinMerge and CompareIt from the [master list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool), but they don't have this feature (unless I'm missing it?). MKS Visual Difference has "combined file" view, but you can only get that as part of an [expensive toolkit of 400 programs](http://www.sovereign-publications.com/mks.htm). I'm looking for a cheaper option. I'd like a GUI not a command-line tool, and I like to be able to view **all** the unchanged lines not just some of them.

[alt text http://img186.imageshack.us/img186/9503/visualdifference2.png](http://img186.imageshack.us/img186/9503/visualdifference2.png)

Comment: I've also requested this feature from CompareIt! http://www.grigsoft.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1471

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried it, but [Guiffy](http://www.guiffy.com/) is a cross platform diff/merge tool. It has a 3-way merge view and is reasonably priced. Here's a [screenshot of 3-way merge](http://www.guiffy.com/images/Guiffy80Vista.jpg).

EDIT (MarkJ) 3-way merge wasn't what I was looking for, but the Guiffy "together view" looks great! I [found](http://www.guiffy.com/shots.html) a screenshot of that:

[alt text http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/4558/guiffytogether.png](http://img41.imageshack.us/img41/4558/guiffytogether.png)

Comment: 3 way merge wasn't what I was looking for, but Guiffy has a "together" view that looks great! I've taken the liberty of editing your answer to show a screenshot of that view from the Guiffy site. +1, and likely to be accepted as **the** answer unless someone outdoes you soon.

Comment: Don't know if that image is a good one or not as imageshack is blocked by my work proxy. If it's what you're after though then that's grand. Would be interested in your opinion of whether its worth the cost over WinMerge or Beyond Compare

Comment: I linked to the original image from my text, here's the link again. Is $60 worth it? Definitely, I'm always comparing files: code reviews and when I'm having a last look at my own work before checking in. http://www.guiffy.com/shots.html

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is `diff -u` which will produce output very close to what you describe.

```
$ diff -10 -u 1 2
--- 1   2009-08-19 12:48:12.847750000 +0200
+++ 2   2009-08-19 12:48:50.925875000 +0200
@@ -1,13 +1,13 @@
 Dim bOk As Integer

 Select Case Col

        Case giCOL_OPTPOLNAME
-               Value = gParamRecOpt.PolName(Row)
+               Value = Trim$(gParamRecOpt.PolName(Row))

        Case giCOL_OPTINCLUDE
                Value = Format$(gParamRecOpt.Include(Row))

        Case giCOL_OPTSHORTLONG
                Value = Format$(gParamRecOpt.Include(Row))


$
```

You can get the diff program for free (GPL) as part of [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).

Comment: Thanks, that is similar to what I'm looking for. Although I'd like a GUI. I'd also like the ability to view *all* the unchanged lines (for reading around source code changes to see whether they're correct or not)